# Axis2: threads BLOCKED in org.apache.axis2.classloader.BeanInfoCache.getCachedBeanInfo

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-axis

Axis2 version: 1.7.1 with WLS 12.1.3

Under heavy load many threads are found in BLOCKED state doing the following:

```
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000109b4b800 nid=0x72 waiting for monitor entry [0xffffffff4b0fc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:67)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:110)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findCustomizerClass(Introspector.java:1245)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetBeanDescriptor(Introspector.java:1239)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:415)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:252)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:214)
    at org.apache.axis2.classloader.BeanInfoCache.getCachedBeanInfo(BeanInfoCache.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getBeanInfo(BeanUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPropertyQnameList(BeanUtil.java:162)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPullParser(BeanUtil.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.processProperties(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:989)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.next(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:848)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.next(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:851)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.StreamWrapper.next(StreamWrapper.java:71)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:663)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:181)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomContainer$build(AxiomContainerSupport.aj:176)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreElementSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreElementSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreElement$beforeDetach(CoreElementSupport.aj:28)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.ajc$interMethodDispatch2$org_apache_axiom_core$beforeDetach(OMElementImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreChildNodeSupport.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNode$beforeDetach(CoreChildNodeSupport.aj)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreChildNodeSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNode$internalDetach(CoreChildNodeSupport.aj:205)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.ajc$interMethodDispatch2$org_apache_axiom_core$internalDetach(OMNodeImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreChildNodeSupport.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNode$internalDetach(CoreChildNodeSupport.aj)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreParentNodeSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreParentNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreParentNode$coreAppendChild(CoreParentNodeSupport.aj:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.coreAppendChild(OMElementImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomContainer$addChild(AxiomContainerSupport.aj:140)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomContainer$addChild(AxiomContainerSupport.aj)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomContainerSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomContainerSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomContainer$addChild(AxiomContainerSupport.aj:114)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processResponse(RPCUtil.java:134)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processResponseAsDocLitWrapped(RPCUtil.java:533)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:159)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:106)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:176)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:163)
    at ws.monitoring.servlet.MonitoringServlet.doPost(MonitoringServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3447)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3417)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2196)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1632)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Looking a request using JFR, we can see how many times the thread goes to BLOCKED state waiting for a monitor lock (each red square). So the thread is getting blocked 92 times waiting for the same monitor lock!. And this can be different in each request.

[image] 
This is generating high contention between threads resulting in high response times. I'm not familiar with axis2 implementation. Can anyone explain why is this occurring and how it can be fixed?.

Comment: Are you using the BeanInfoCache.getCachedBeanInfo method directly or is it being used internally by some dependency? There is a note in the [Javadocs](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/classloader/BeanInfoCache.html) regarding classloader leaks. There are also some specific configuration suggestions for WebLogic, have you followed [these](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html)?

Comment: I can't tell if this is something been called directly, I believe axis2 does it automatically. Yes I already saw that recommendations and asked to review them to development team.